# Detail Disclosure loading on top of the previous detail disclosure

Tags: ios, swift

I have a map view with annotations and every annotation has a corresponding date with day, month, and time.

I'm pushing the day to the new view controller then using a `switch` to see what day of the month it falls on and then displaying the corresponding calendar icon. I can't put the `func` anywhere other than viewDidAppear which cause a brief lag and two, prevents me from using

```
for view in self.view.subviews {
    view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

So two questions:

- how can I call the dayCalendar function before viewDidAppear (anywhere else I've tried to put the code, it returns a nil)
- how do I prevent my detailDisclosures from appearing on top of one another?

This is the code responsible for showing the image:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    dayCalendar()
}

func dayCalendar() {

    switch day {
    case 1:
        let calendarDay = "Calendar 1-50.png"
        let calendarDayImage = UIImage(named: calendarDay)
        let calendarDayImageView = UIImageView(image: calendarDayImage!)
        calendarDayImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 25 , y: 350, width: 50, height: 50)
        self.view.addSubview(calendarDayImageView)
    case 8:
        let calendarDay = "Calendar 8-50.png"
        let calendarDayImage = UIImage(named: calendarDay)
        let calendarDayImageView = UIImageView(image: calendarDayImage!)
        calendarDayImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 25 , y: 350, width: 50, height: 50)
        self.view.addSubview(calendarDayImageView)
    case 11:
        let calendarDay = "Calendar 11-50.png"
        let calendarDayImage = UIImage(named: calendarDay)
        let calendarDayImageView = UIImageView(image: calendarDayImage!)
        calendarDayImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 25 , y: 350, width: 50, height: 50)
        self.view.addSubview(calendarDayImageView)

    case 12:
        blahh blahh blahh all the way down

    case 31:
        let calendarDay = "Calendar 30-50.png"
        let calendarDayImage = UIImage(named: calendarDay)
        let calendarDayImageView = UIImageView(image: calendarDayImage!)
        calendarDayImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 25 , y: 350, width: 50, height: 50)
        self.view.addSubview(calendarDayImageView)
    default:
        println("Default")
        break
    }

}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: why are you actually switching? As far as I can tell the code can be reduced to

```
func dayCalendar() {
    if day < 1 || day > 31 {
        return 
    }
    let calendarDay = "Calendar \(day)-50.png"
    let calendarDayImage = UIImage(named: calendarDay)
    let calendarDayImageView = UIImageView(image: calendarDayImage!)
    calendarDayImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 25 , y: 350, width: 50, height: 50)
    self.view.addSubview(calendarDayImageView)
}
```

You might want to move the call to [`viewWillAppear`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:).

To fix the overlaying of the detail closures you have two options:

- remove the added `calendarDayImageView` every time you display a new day.

or (much better)

- reuse the already added image view if it is already present (might want to create a lazy variable) and just change the image it is displaying.

The later one you can achieve in the following way:

```
// add this variable to your class
lazy var calendarDayImageView: UIImageView = {
    [unowned self] in
    let imageV = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 25 , y: 350, width: 50, height: 50))
    self.view.addSubview(imageV)
    return imageV
}()

// change the dayCalender to make use of the newly added variable
func dayCalendar() {
    if day < 1 || day > 31 {
        return 
    }
    let calendarDay = "Calendar \(day)-50.png"
    let calendarDayImage = UIImage(named: calendarDay)
    calendarDayImageView.image = calendarDayImage
}
```

Alternatively you can just move the initialization of the view inside viewDidLoad and have `dayCalender` again only set the actual image - but i like lazy vars ;)

Comment: This is extremely helpful. But how do I create a lazy variable and change the image it is displaying?

Comment: @PabloPicasso i added the lazy var and a little more explanation